# AR frameworks that can detect multiple instances of same image target

Tags: android, augmented-reality, vuforia, artoolkit

I am looking for an Augmented Reality framework that can simultaneously detect multiple identical image targets, in one scene.

For example, I have three image cards, each three has the same image.
The AR framework should be able to detect those and place 3D models correctly on top of each three cards.

The framework should also need to have mobile support (Android).

I know it has been done before, for example:
[Elements 4D by DAQRI: an app for teaching chemistry](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.daqri.elements4dbydaqri)

I tried [Vuforia](https://www.vuforia.com/) but apparently it does not support multiple identical images, as stated in these forum posts: [One](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity-extension-technical-discussion/cant-tracks-same-targets#comment-2060706), [Two](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/object-recognition/about-same-image-targets), [Three](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/qcar-api/multiple-image-targets-simultaneously-same-image)

Do you have other recommendations?
Does [ARToolkit](https://artoolkit.org/) has this capability?

Comment: Theoretically ARToolKit has this ability and I have seen it done but you need to change some of the code files and rebuild it in order to work

Answer (score 0):

Wikitude does support multiple instances of the same image.
You could take a look at the documentation and/or samples.

[Wikitude Native SDK Documentation](https://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/androidnative/imagerecognitionnative.html#multiple-image-targets-tracking)

[Wikitude JS SDK Documentation](https://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/android/multipletargets.html#multiple-targets)

This works for also for Xamarin/Cordova/Titanium and Unity.